# invalid menu item when upgrading to WordPress 5.5

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a site with WooCommerce, Storefront and a child theme. When I upgraded the site to WordPress 5.5.1 a page menu item called "Product Categories" says it is invalid. I am uncertain what happened to this page. It is not found when searching.

The site uses a plugin called Max Mega Menu and there is an extensive product menu that was build under "Product Categories." It there any way via MySql or other to reassign a menu item to another page so that it is no longer "invalid" without having to rebuild the entire menu?

Comment: I'd look in the wp_options table for the menu configuration, which will probably be a PHP-serialized structure starting something like `a:99:{`. You probably want to use PHP to unserialize the value, edit it and serialize the result to get the new value to paste into the database. The exact schema here is likely to be specific to the Max Mega Menu plugin.

Comment: It would be interesting to work out why it thinks its invalid though. I can't think of anything in 5.5.1 that would have broken it?

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: It is invalid because the parent page was put in the trash and emptied. When ia new version of WordPress is installed it updates the permalinks probably. I decided to simply create a page then rebuild the menu. thanks...

Comment: Glad you solved it! Maybe post that as an answer? Thanks!